# Accessing a json file in php

Tags: php, json

I have a json file like this:

```
{"results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "4400",
           "short_name" : "4400",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Upper Austria",
           "short_name" : "OÖ",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Austria",
           "short_name" : "AT",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "4400, Austria",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 48.06669549999999,
              "lng" : 14.4687485
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 47.9987654,
              "lng" : 14.3408425
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 48.0418838,
           "lng" : 14.4078882
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 48.06669549999999,
              "lng" : 14.4687485
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 47.9987654,
              "lng" : 14.3408425
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
  }
],
"status" : "OK"
}
```

and everytime i try to access it i get undefined index location, i want to access this part:

```
"location" : {
       "lat" : 48.0418838,
       "lng" : 14.4078882
    },
```

with this:

```
$url1="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=AT-".$a."&sensor=false";
$unparsed_json = file_get_contents($url1);
$data =(array) json_decode($unparsed_json);
echo $unparsed_json;
$latlng= $data['results']['location']['lat'];
echo $latlng;
```

but everything I try gives result null. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using arrays in your json code and need to reference items accordingly, also your location is located in the geometry entity.
Try out with this `$latlng= $data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];`

Here's even a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fLtu8/) in JS just to show the concept. Use the line above in your PHP code.

Comment: @juliesmith mark his answer as accepted then. Otherwise, in the future, there will be less motivation to answer your questions.

Comment: i know that, but i could not do it right away since you need to wait before accept it :)